# Sending a POST request with the request URI of '/' to the Cassini Web Server leading to a 405 error. Why?

Tags: c#, cassini, http-status-code-405

I am sending a POST request using HTTPWebRequest from the client to the Cassini Web Server on the remote machine configured to accept remote requests. But, I am not specifying a file as part of the URL. I am sending the request directly to the server as in "http://172.34.142.12:8080/". However, I am unable to receive a proper response and getting a "405 Method not allowed" error. I am using Cassini 3.5. Any suggestions as to why this might be happening?

Comment: just to confirm what you're somewhat implying - GET calls from the same remote host to the same url are working fine?  Also, do the POST calls work if you're on the same machine? I've noticed POST and PUT calls to Cassini failing for me as well, but I never dug into why (these were to localhost, so likely an unrelated reason)

Comment: I haven't tried with GET. However, POST does not work even on the same machine. I still get the same problem. I need to use POST, since I am sending data to the server directly, and on the server side, I've modified Cassini to process the sent data, like creating a new process based on the data.

Comment: To confirm: It worked with GET(on a remote machine) after some modifying code and playing with it. However, I am unable to do it using POST just as James said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassini is hardcoded to not accept requests from any host other than the one running it.  It's programmed this way for security reasons.

If you really need this functionality, you'll have to build your own version of it.  There's a few walkthroughs around on how to do this, [here's one](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/11711/1954).

Comment: The version I am using is this and this accepts remote requests too: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dmitryr/archive/2008/10/03/cassini-for-framework-3-5.aspx

Answer (score 1):

My company makes a product called the Neokernel that might help you: [www.neokernel.com](http://www.neokernel.com)

The Neokernel is *NOT* based on Cassini. It is a professional, embeddable ASP.NET web server in a small, self contained assembly with logging, SSL, support for multiple ASP.NET apps, programmatic configuration, support for virtual directories, and it runs any web app that IIS does. It also works with the Mono framework; we developed it because there are a number of problems with Cassini (and the various projects derived from it).